# Disable rest of the numeric boxes once sum reaches 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a setup where I have multiple rows in a table asking for numeric input. I want to disable rest of the text boxes as soon as sum reaches 100.

My alert in condition is working fine but unable to select the empty text boxes to disable them. Also, alert is working only if I enter 100 in first input box. For rest of the boxes even alert is not working.

Please help, below is my code-

```
function checkTotal() {
    var sum=0;
    $("#fieldset_Q14 table tbody tr").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).find("input:text:last").val());
        if (sum==100) {
            //alert("test");
            $("input:text[value='']").prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else{
            $("input:text[value='']").prop('disabled',false);
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(checkTotal);
$("input:text").keyup(checkTotal);
```

Comment: You need to check if `sum>=100`

Comment: It will be easier if you share your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this line of code.

```
sum += parseInt($(this).find("input:text:last").val());
```

When you `parseInt` empty textboxes it will return **NaN** .. So you must take care to return 0 in case of Nan. Change the above line to

```
sum += parseInt($(this).find("input:text:last").val()) || 0;
```

Also you must filter out all the `inputs` which are empty by using this code

```
$('input:text').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ""; })
```

And then disable it..

Here is a **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1xm16g7/2/)**

Comment: but I am setting up sum=0 outside the loop and not inside each function. Each function stores only the updated value. Also when I am entering 10,80,10 alert is working fine. It is not working only in case when first box is empty and rest of them are filled.

Comment: @VaibhavLuthra forgive me.. I overlooked the syntax, I updated my answer.. I dont see any other issue with your code.

Comment: I am fine with sum being >100, we want respondent to be able to change answers if the sum is >100 @Reddy

Comment: @VaibhavLuthra so you want to disable exactly when sum is 100?

Comment: yes, I want my disable functionality to run only when sum=100 @Reddy

Comment: count is not an issue, issue is that sum stops working if any of the text box is empty and unable to select empty text boxes when sum is 100

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111760/discussion-between-vaibhav-luthra-and-reddy).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code i think this code will do needful for your requirement :)

```
            function checkTotal() {
                var sum=0;
                $("#fieldset_Q14 table tbody tr").each(function() {
                    sum += parseInt($(this).find("input:text:last").val());
                    if (sum==100) {
                        //alert("test");
                        $("input").each(function(){
                            if($(this).val() == '')
                                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        $("input").each(function(){
                            if($(this).val() == '')
                                $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is not working because when you try to sum empty values it generates a NaN result. Also, you can compare result after complete sum calculation.

```
function checkTotal() {
var sum=0;
$("#fieldset_Q14 table tbody tr").each(function() {
    var num = parseInt($(this).find("input:text:last").val()) || 0;
    sum += parseInt(num);
});
if (sum==100) {
  $('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; }).prop('disabled',true);
}
else {
  $('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; }).prop('disabled',false);
}
```

}

See https://jsfiddle.net/p556xprt/ for a working example.